# How to add an element between items within ngFor

Tags: angular, foreach, ngfor, angular-template

I have this piece of template where I am loop through the items and creating a buttons:

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
  <p>
    <button
      type="button"
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
    >
      {{ button.text }}
    </button>
  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to add a text in between the buttons.

[image]

The list can contain more than 2 buttons so I want that same text to appear between all buttons. And I want this text to be centered right in between the buttons as per pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert your text into the repeater if it is not the last button:

```js
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons; let last=last">
  <p>
    <button
      type="button"
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
    >
      {{ button.text }}
    </button>
  </p>
  <div *ngIf="!last">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it seems works, however I do have this problem now the text which is within div once placed between buttons it is not centered. How to center that in between the buttons?

Comment: Add a class to the `div` and use `css` to style it-

Comment: Do you think there is no way to other fix that say by changing/improving the layout? Is css the only option?

Comment: This is the way... <••>

Answer (score 0):

well, you could just simply get the index of the *ngFor like "*ngFor="let button of buttons;let i = index""  and then

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index">
  <p>
 
    <button
      type="button"
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
    >
      {{ button.text }}
    </button>
  </p>
       <div *ngIf="i== 2">this will show after the second iteration of the
  *ngFor</div>

</div>
```